# Enable checkbox if text changes in textarea

Tags: jquery, checkbox, indexing, textarea

I have a big form with hundreds of inputs and textareas inside a table. The code is like this (updated with the exact structure):

```
<form>
<table>
<tr>
<td><input name="cx[]" value="a" type="checkbox"></td>
<td>...</td>
<td>...</td>
<td>...</td>    
<td>...</td>
<td>...</td>
<td>...</td>
<td>...</td>
<td><textarea name="tx1[]">...</textarea></td>
<td><textarea name="tx2[]">...</textarea></td>
<td><textarea name="tx3[]">...</textarea></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
...
...
</table>
</form>
```

When the user changes a textarea value, I would like to automatically activate the checkbox asociated in that row (same array index). This is because when the user submits the form, I need to know (with the checkboxes) which elements have changed, to store/update them or not, instead of populate all the textareas.

It could be great to enable the checkbox only if the text typed in the textarea has changed its original text (not just typed some text).

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Code edited to show exact structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to know the index values, as long as the structures you provided are consistent.

```
$('textarea').on('keyup',function(){
    if(this.value.length > 0){
        $(this).prev().prop('checked',true);
    } else {
        $(this).prev().prop('checked',false);
    }
});
```

You can optimize this as needed, but so long as the checkbox you want to activate preceeds that of the textbox value being changed, you can get away with just using `.prev()`.

**EDIT**

So it looks like you have a single checkbox per row with name `cx[]` that you want to check if any of the textbox values change from their original value? How about something like this:

```
$('textarea').on({
    focus:function(){
        $(this).data('curval',this.value);
    },
    'blur keyup':function(){
        if(this.value !== $(this).data('curval')){
            $(this).prevAll('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked',true);
        }
    }
});
```

The `focus` function will store the existing value of the textarea when it is focused, and then compares the value when it is either blurred or keyupped (blur is in case someone copy / pastes via mouse). If it has changed, then it cycles back through the DOM tree on the same level until it reaches the checkbox and checks it.

The lack of "unchecking it" is because that gets infinitely more complex to implement ... even if you "change it back" it is a change from the previous value and therefore will be a change. Another note is that I did the selector based on the assumption it was the only checkbox ... if you had others, you would choose a selector based on the name, like `.prevAll('[name="cx[]"]')`.

Hopefully this is what you're looking for.

**EDIT 2**

Turns out I was oversimplifying ... `.prevAll()` wouldn't work because you need to check the parents and then previous children. I changed it to this:

```
$(".tx").on({
    focus:function(){
        $(this).data('curval',this.value);
    },
    'blur keyup':function(){
        if(this.value !== $(this).data('curval')){
            var val = this.value;
            $(this).data('curval',val).parents('tr').find('.cx').prop('checked',true);
        }
    }
});
```

This works. It assigns the new value to `curval`, then searches for the parent of the row (`tr`), and finds the checkbox. I couldn't get it working based on the selectors involving names (which are horribly inefficient anyway, you should avoid attribute selectors like the plague), so I just gave the appropriate items classes. This is a much cleaner selector.

[Here is the updated jsFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/WrJPw/3/)

Comment: Correct answer for the original code I posted (summary), but the code wasn't exactly the same so it doesn't work. I have updated the code. My fault.

Comment: Alright updated my answer, hopefully this is more in line with what you're looking for.

Comment: I have checked the code and I can't get it working. Here you can try it:
http://jsfiddle.net/WrJPw/

Comment: @amparo69 - updated my answer with a working jsFiddle. sorry, my original code didn't work because of the parent / child heirarchy. my second edit works, provided an updated jsFiddle.

Comment: Yes, that works, but to check the first textarerea value against the latest one, keyup event should not be used.

With that solution, how do I get the array index of the checkbox/textarea in that row?

Comment: with this solution, you dont **need** to get the array index of the checkbox for that row to alter it, thats the whole point. and if `keyup` doesnt suit your needs, then just use `blur`.

Answer (score 0):

I also don't know how to get the index in that case, but maybe this can help you:

```
$.each( $("textarea[name='tx[]']"), function( key, value ) {
    alert( key + ": " + value );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
....
if (this.value.length > 0) {
   $(this).prev('input').prop('checked',true)
} else {
   $(this).prev('input').prop('checked',false)
}
```

this will work as long as the checkbox is the previous element of the textarea(as it is now).

Comment: Correct answer for the original code I posted (summary), but the code wasn't exactly the same so it doesn't work. I have updated the code. My fault.

Answer (score 0):

I have found this working code using test/error:

```
$("textarea[name='tx1[]']").keyup(function(){
    //inArray: Search for a specified value within an array and return its index (or -1 if not found).
    var index = jQuery.inArray(this,$("textarea[name='tx1[]']"));
    if(this.value.length > 0){
        $("input[name='cx[]']").eq(index).prop('checked',true);
    }
})
```

Improvement that would be apreciated:

-Enable the checkbox only if the content of the textarea has changed, not just typed some text (compare original text with newer one).